# Store Locator Example - can't get records to be returned

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please. I'm trying to learn how to build a 'Store Locator' and I'm working through the example shown on the Google developer site.

I've added the records to my database and have created the HTML form, but I can't get the php script to work i.e. the are no records returned.

```
<?php  
require("phpfile.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

I've been looking at this for a while now and I can't see where I've gone wrong. Could someone perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just compared the query you're using against the one I used for a very similar application I wrote. Everything is exactly the same, except the single quotes around your variables - `center_lat, center_lng, radius`

So, assuming that those variables are set correctly, removing the single quotes around them should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. If I've understood this correctly, it's the quotes on these 3 lines: 
$center_lat = $_GET[lat]; 
$center_lng = $_GET[lng]; 
$radius = $_GET[radius];

If I've got this right, I've removed them but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Do you just get an empty result set back? Maybe the query is working, but it really doesn't find anything close to the specified latitude/longitude...

Comment: Hi, many thanks for bearing with me on this. Please find the link to my test page. http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/distance.html
I know that there are records where part of the address is 'Mountain view' but when I try and search for this, I just receive 'Mountain view' not found. So I'm not sure where the problem lies. Kind regards

Comment: If you could provide some test data, like the entries you have in the database and the latitude/longitude variables you are using, that would help pinpoint where the problem actually lies - the logic or the query.

Comment: Hi, it's ok I've just worked it out. The example is for api v2, not V3. Apologies for messing you around. Many thanks for your time and trouble. kind regards.